# How to make background of madal scrollable while modal is open?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have created a bootstrap modal,when it pops up the vertical scrollbar of the background page gets disable and contents of the background page move to their right side in the same amount of scrollbars width.So i want to avoid that move of the contents of page, and make background scrollable while modal is open? (note that i am using bootstrap 3.0.0 modal)
So,Please give me some hint to do that.Thank you in advance . . .

Answer (score 0):

Change the CSS like this..

```
#myModal .modal-content
{
  height:200px;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

If you don't want the scroll bar on the entire modal, use modal-body instead:

```
#myModal .modal-body
{
  height:200px;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/88983

Comment: No ,no @Skelly i think you mis understood , i am trying to say that when i open the modal the background page's vertical scrollbar gets disabled means the page from where the modal pops up . .I want that page to be scrollable and not the modal . .

Answer (score 0):

Here i come to know that when modal is opened bootstrap adds the 'modal-open' class to the body ,and then we can apply our css to this class.I have found solution for this by changing my css:

```
.modal-open{overflow:auto !important;}
```